# Apache host many laravel projects in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have set up an Apache server with the following URL: `https://dev.mysite.com`.  I am now creating subdirectories for each project that I have in development.  For example it might be `https://dev.mysite.com/project`, or `https://dev.mysite.com/anotherproject`.  Some of the projects in development utilize the Laravel, and the Laravel Lumen, framework(s).

I will not be using a vhost file for each project, as they will be existing in subdirectories.  The goal is to be able to visit `https://dev.mysite.com/project/public/` and have the Laravel, or Lumen, application served to the user visiting the project.  I am ok with having the client visit /public/ to view their project.  This is not happening.

`-Indexes` has been set on the server's virtualhost file to prevent listing files/directories in the browser.

When I navigate to `{url}/project/public/heartbeat` (for example) the route is not being served (or parsed) correctly.  When I do a `die` of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` I get `/project/public/heartbeat`.  The route `heartbeat` is set up as follows: `$app->get('/heartbeat', 'Controller@method');`.  Visiting this url gives the typical HTTP not found exception from the Illuminate code.  However; when I add `project/public/` to the beginning of the route path (resulting in `$app->get('/project/public/heartbeat'...`) it works.  I have tried adding the `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteBase /project/public/` and `RewriteBase /project/` settings to the .htaccess file and neither work.  I do know that the .htaccess is being used (I can add 'asdf' to the file and break it).  The mod_rewrite module is enabled.

Here are the configuration files for the vhost, and the project/public/.htaccess file.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev.mysite.com

Redirect permanent / https://dev.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName dev.mysite.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/public

<Directory /var/www/public>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LogLevel warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-access.log combined

ErrorDocument 403 https://dev.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.  Again, end goal is to be able to visit `https://dev.mysite.com/project/public/` and have the Laravel, Lumen, etc. application served to the user visiting the project.

Answer (score 0):

[Setup your vhost](http://www.contecha.com/blog/setting-up-a-local-development-url-with-apache/) as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/some/directory/mysite.dev"
   ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice you need to setup an initial 'root' project at `/some/directory/mysite.dev`. This doesn't have to be a laravel app, all it needs to have is a `.htaccess` file, and maybe you might want an `index.html` file in there so when you visit mysite.dev, you can at least see something. This is optional though.

In the `/some/directory/mysite.dev` folder, create a `.htaccess` file and add the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   # We need this to stop the rewrite rule looping as the URI
   # and directory both start with 'SubProject'
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SubProject/

   # direct all requests that start with SubProject
   RewriteRule ^ SubProject/?(.*)/?$ /SubProject/public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

When you visit `mysite.dev/SubProject` the `index.php` file from that project should be loaded.